# Control screen touch region Windows 10 UWP app

Tags: uwp

I need to disable touch input on certain parts of the screen.  In other words, if the user touches inside a region, no input is generated.  Outside the region, touch works as normal.

My app is UWP app running on Windows 10.  The specific scenario is that there two touch screens.  In some cases, I need to disable input on the second touch screen... Preferably, inside a certain region. To avoid focus stealing from the other touch screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlay a `Rectangle`/`Grid` with a transparent background on top of the elements you want to block input from. You can allow or disallow input by toggling `IsHitTestVisible` (or `Visibility`).

Comment: Better use **Rectangle** instead of **Grid**. It's much lighter.

Comment: @Jet Do you have a source for that?

Comment: It's just have more options and more sophisticated rather than Rectangle for mask purpose. Rectangle is lighter on XAML Layout events on UI thread. Your answer is totally correct.

Comment: You're probably right, but without knowing the implementation we can't be sure. And it's just one control, I wouldn't worry about that kind of micro-optimization (unless it's within a DataTemplate for a list or something like that).